# How to mimick medium trust?

Tags: nhibernate, medium-trust

Is it possible to change my local dev environment (preferrably just a single IIS site) to work under medium trust?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set this in your web.config see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkscy493.aspx) and [Defining a Trust Level for your web application](http://blogs.runatserver.com/ppare/archive/2009/04/15/defining-a-trust-level-for-your-web-application.aspx)